# Grails 3.3.2 - Error [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

Tags: grails

I'm beginner with Grails and I want to do upgrade my plugin in Grails 2 to Grails 3.

What I have done:

1. I created my plugin ( create plugin ) with Grails 3.3.2
2. `grails run-app`
3. I recopied my plugin who is in Grails 2 in Grails 3

When I run my app, following error appears:

```
2018-01-24 12:20:27.854 ERROR --- [           main] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:616)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:299)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:548)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at pap_mailgv332.Application.main(Application.groovy:10)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:693)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:606)
    ... 22 common frames omitted

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2048m; support was removed in 8.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
 Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Version :

Grails : 3.3.2

Form : 6.1.8

IDE : IntelliJ 2017.2

I tried much forum who were saying to change version of gorm, spring-boot-autoconfigure, groovy, spring-security-core, hibernate-java8 and more

But nothing is working

Comment: whats the dependency u added for springsecurity??

Comment: I added this 3 dependency :                                                          compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1"
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-acl:3.2.0'
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.0.0.RELEASE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2018-01-25 13:29:24.244 ERROR --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper.setConversionService(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;)V
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:147)
at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:548)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.bindSpringProfiles(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:541)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.handleProfileProperties(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:533)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.doLoadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:494)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:473)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at pap_mailgv332.Application.main(Application.groovy:10)
```

solved by this ==>

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my bug with ==>

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.2.RELEASE'
```

but now I have an other problem :

```
2018-01-25 13:21:35.562 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in pap_mailgv332.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugins.mail.MailService] from plugin [mail] : grails/artefact/Service
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at pap_mailgv332.Application.main(Application.groovy:10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=2048m; support was removed in 8.0
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugins.mail.MailService] from plugin [mail] : grails/artefact/Service
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: grails.plugins.exceptions.PluginException: Failed to initialize class [grails.plugins.mail.MailService] from plugin [mail] : grails/artefact/Service
at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.initializeProvidedArtefacts(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:175)
at org.grails.plugins.BinaryGrailsPlugin.<init>(BinaryGrailsPlugin.java:104)
at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.createBinaryGrailsPlugin(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:375)
at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.findCorePlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:362)
at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.attemptLoadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:314)
at grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.loadPlugins(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:224)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:90)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:78)
at grails.boot.config.GrailsAutoConfiguration.grailsApplicationPostProcessor(GrailsAutoConfiguration.groovy:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 23 common frames omitted
```

Solved by this :

```
maven { url "https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/"}
compile 'org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:2.5.6.SEC01'
```